# Permanently switching user in Capistrano 3 (separate authorization & deploy)

Tags: ruby, deployment, capistrano

We have following pattern in server management - all users do have their own user, but deploy is fully performed by special deploy user, without direct login possibility.

We used this method in Capistrano 2.x:

```
default_run_options[:shell] = "sudo -u deploy bash"

$ cap stage deploy -s user=thisisme
```

I'm aware that Capistrano 3.x has method to switch user directly:

```
task :install do
    on roles(:all) do
        as :deploy do
            execute :whoami
        end
    end
end
```

But this code will fill all tasks, and default tasks will not inherit deploy user anyway. Is it ever possible to set up login user directly without dragging this code to each task?

Answer (score 7):

Since I had received no proper answer and didn't got the idea myself, I decided to ask authors. Capistrano 3.x uses SSHKit to manage remote execution commands, [and here's their answer](https://github.com/capistrano/sshkit/issues/154#issuecomment-47431649):

You could try overriding the command map such that every command gets prefixed with the desired sudo string. https://github.com/capistrano/sshkit/blob/master/README.md#the-command-map

```ruby
SSHKit.config.command_map = Hash.new do |hash, command|
  hash[command] = "<<sudo stuff goes here>> #{command}"
end
```

The documentation says "this may not be wise, but it would be possible". YMMV