# How to set a default shell or sudo to a user in capistrano 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, shell, capistrano, capistrano3

I'm currently in the process of moving from Capistrano 2.x to 3.x for a rails application and running into the following issue. The general setup on the server contains a deploy user that should be the one responsible for deploying, however when a user goes to deploy, they connect to the server with their own user name.

In Capistrano 2.x, I was able to accomplish this using the `default_shell` option.

```
set :default_shell, "sudo -u deploy /bin/sh"
```

This does not work in Capistrano 3.x. Is there any way to either set the shell, or sudo to the deploy user in a before hook?

Things I have tried:

1. Setting the `:default_shell` option does not work as mentioned.
2. I tried sudo-ing to the user in a before hook. Something like `sudo -s -u deploy`, which works fine outside of capistrano. My user is set up for password-less sudo to the deploy user by the way. But in Capistrano it runs the command and then just hangs.
3. Per [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24400184/permanently-switching-user-in-capistrano-3-separate-authorization-deploy), it seems possible to prepend `sudo -u deploy` to every command, but this doesn't seem to fully work. A couple commands in, the deploy still aborts with an exception executing as my user on a Permission denied.
4. I can individually map some commands as `SSHKit.config.command_map[:git] = 'sudo -u deploy git'`, but this does not seem like the best method and I do not have a list of all the commands that I would need to map.

**UPDATE:**
Per my third attempt, mapping all of the commands generally seems to work.

```
SSHKit.config.command_map = Hash.new do |hash, command|
  hash[command] = "sudo -u deploy #{command}"
end
```

But not completely. One of the first things capistrano does is run git:check which uploads the file `/tmp/git-ssh.sh`. But this file gets created with my user, not the deploy user.

Comment: I have not tried it (and the documentation is pretty sparse), but this might be what you need: https://github.com/fundingcircle/sshkit-backends-netssh_global

Comment: @MattBrictson Interesting.. That does seem to do what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

If you just need to change the deployment user, in capistrano 3 it's a lot easier. Assuming you have this file structure:

```
config
|__deploy
   |__production.rb
   |__staging.rb

Capfile
```

Then in your production.rb or staging.rb (depending on what environment you're deploying to):

```
set :user, 'deploy'

server 'example.com', user: fetch(:user)
```

Comment: Yes, setting the user is possible, but not switching after connecting. The way security is set up I can't log in as deploy.