# How to switch user permanently using capistrano

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano

Using Capistrano i logged as a default user which does not have access privilege. I need to switch to a different user in remote 'deploy user' to perform certain tasks.

Below is my script

```
set :user, "sasi"
set :group, "sasi"

set :switch_user do
  password = Capistrano::CLI.ui.ask "deployuser password:"
  run "whoami"
  run("su - 'deployuser'") do |channel, stream, output|
    channel.send_data("#{password}\n") if output
  end
end
```

Help me in switching to a different user permanently using Capistrano.

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea how Capistrano can do this. But I found an answer which I hope could help you.

[Permanently switching user in Capistrano 3 (separate authorization & deploy)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24400184/permanently-switching-user-in-capistrano-3-separate-authorization-deploy)